# JavaMail message getReceivedDate() and getSentDate()

Tags: email, jakarta-mail, email-client

I'm using JavaMail 1.4.7, and a specific message in my mail account contains the header:

```
Received: from ... (localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1])
by ... (lmtpd) with LMTP id 25811.002;
Tue, 12 Nov 2013 16:52:11 +0100 (CET)
Subject: CONSEGNA: numerodacontare
Date: Tue, 12 Nov 2013 16:52:11 +0100
```

And for this message

`getReceivedDate() =Tue Nov 12 16:52:10 CET 2013`

`getSentDate() =Tue Nov 12 16:52:11 CET 2013`

So it seems that the message has been received before sending it.

1. How should this be interpreted?
2. What is exactly the difference?
3. Is this behavior common for all mail server?

Comment: Could the "sent" date be from the other system, and could that system have a clock that is set wrongly?

Comment: Yes.  Note also that the received date is set by the mail server and should be pretty accurate relative to the clock setting on the mail server.  The sent date is set by the sender and could be anything.  Really, **anything**.  It might not be the time the message was actually sent.  It might be in the distant past or the future.  It might be lying to make it appear that the message was sent earlier than it was.  We hope that it's fairly accurate, but there are no guarantees.  Be careful how much you trust it.

Comment: So, the received date is not part of the header but is dynamically returned from the imap server?